# Batch script that makes a numbered menu to view log files

Tags: batch-file, scripting, cmd

I have recently started to learn how to make batch files. I have a folder that contains bunch of internet related log files. When I run the .cmd file (located in the same folder) I want it to be able to find out how many log files are in the folder and make a numbered menu from it. So lets say there are twenty files in the folder, then the user must be able to select from 1 to 21. 21 will close the batch file. Here is what I have done so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set RawData1=TempData%random%.tmp
set FileCtr=0    

:MAIN
dir *.log /b | findstr /i /n ".log" > %RawData1%

for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (%RawData1%) do set FileCtr=%%a
set /a ExitCode=%FileCtr% + 1
set UserChoice=%ExitCode%

echo.
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
echo     Weblog File Viewer                              
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++++    
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:." %%a in (%RawData1%) do echo %%a. %%b
echo %Exitcode%. To Quit.
set /p UserChoice= Choose item number from menu (%UserChoice%):    

echo\
echo user entered: %UserChoice%
pause
:THEEND
del /q %RawData1%
```

So what this batch file can do for now is that it figures out the number of log files and makes a numbered menu from it. Of course it won't show the filetype which is how I wanted it. So "Kelley-Blue-Book.log" for example is shown only as "Kelley-Blue-Book". However, if the user selects say number 4 from the list the program will terminate because I couldn't figure out how to make it actually open the desired log file using notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions 

    set RawData1=TempData%random%.tmp

    rem Get numbered list of files
    dir /b "*.log" | findstr /i /n ".log" > %RawData1%

    rem We could use 0 as exitCode, 
    rem but to keep original behaviour
    rem lets count the number of files
    for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('type %RawData1% ^| find /c /v "" ') do set /A ExitCode=%%f + 1

    if %ExitCode%==0 (
        echo No log files
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem show menu
    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:." %%a in (%RawData1%) do echo %%a. %%b
    echo %Exitcode%. To Quit.
    set UserChoice=%ExitCode%
    set /p UserChoice= Choose item number from menu (%UserChoice%):

    if "%UserChoice%"=="" goto :EOF
    if "%UserChoice%"=="%ExitCode%" goto endProcess

    rem Search indicated file in list
    set SelectedFile=
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('findstr /B "%UserChoice%:" %RawData1%') do set SelectedFile=%%f

    if "%SelectedFile%"=="" (
        echo Incorrect selection
        goto endProcess
    )

    if not exist %SelectedFile% (
        echo File deleted
        goto endProcess
    )

    notepad %SelectedFile%

:endProcess

    del /q %RawData1%
```

Comment: Close to my own approach. However it terminates the script when the log file is closed. I don't want it to terminate unless I choose to, this way I can view other log files. I probably should have mentioned it though. I modified it to do that. Anyhow, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

#### This should do what you want:

```
@echo Off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Count=0"
pushd "%~dp0"

echo.
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
echo     Weblog File Viewer                              
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
for %%A in (*.log) do (
    set /a "Count+=1"
    set "Menu[!Count!]=%%~fA"
    set "Number=   !Count!"
    echo !Number:~-3!. %%~nA
)
set /a "Count+=1"
set "Number=   %Count%"
echo %Number:~-3%. To Quit.

:Prompt
set "UserChoice="
set /p "UserChoice= Choose item number from menu (%Count%):"
if not defined UserChoice goto Prompt
set "UserChoice=%UserChoice:"=%"

if "%UserChoice%"=="%Count%" goto Done
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('set Menu') do (
    if /i "Menu[%UserChoice%]"=="%%~A" (
        notepad "%%~fB"
        set "UserChoice="
    )
)
if defined UserChoice echo Invalid Choice.
goto Prompt

:Done
popd
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Let me know if you want any explanations.

Comment: argh - two minutes too late. But you added some errorhandling. +1 :)

Comment: Maybe change `set /p "UserChoice= Choose item number from menu (%Count%):"` to `set /p "UserChoice= Choose item number from menu (%Count% for exit):"` and delete `echo %Number:~-3%. To Quit.` ?

Comment: @Stephan  Yep, those changes are fine with me **`:)`**  It can be easily tailored to fit whatever the OP wants.

Comment: Good suggestion Stephan. David, I can understand it all. Though I wanted the batch script to create a temp file and delete it when it terminates. Like Microsoft Word. Still, works just fine and I like it that it doesn't terminate when the log file is closed. So I can view other logs. Thanks a lot.